# Fonts and formatting

Tags: formatting, packages

2. I have tried to use `\usepackage{verdana}` but when I latex it, it says fonts are not available.  I have tried several downloads but none is working properly.  Can someone point me in the correct direction?
3. If I want to have the first page (cover page) in Verdana font and the 2nd and subsequent pages in Times New Roman, how do I do so?    I know it is of a weird format but this is what we have been told to do for writing our exams - the only acceptable format.   I tried putting \usepackage{times} before the start of the second page but latex gave me an error message.

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You have four (4) distinct questions, please split them up and ask them separately.

Comment: Do you compile with `pdflatex` or `xelatex+fontspec`? Also, what is your distribution?

Comment: The question now has question 2 and 3 and the only answer is about question 1 and 4. LOL

Comment: Also, no MWE with list of used packages.

Comment: Kris, I think that you have deleted your point 1 ad 4 because @DG' pointed out that you should ask multiple unrelated questions in separate posts and because Bernard already answered them. This is not how this site works.

Comment: Hi all.   The reason why it is deleted is because someone messaged me and told me what the answer is.  As soon as I deleted points 1 and 4, I saw Bernard's reply.   Hence this situation - obviously unintentional.

Comment: Should I delete this and restart again or...?

Comment: @Kris put the questions 1 and 4 back in so they match Bernard's answer. Then take out 2 and 3 and ask a new question about verdana and font changing

Answer (score 1):

I can answer to questions  1 and 4:

1. Load `enumitem` and use

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
   ```

Alternatively, if you want this style for all your enumerate environments of level, say, 2, you can can add to your preamble

```
\setlist[enumerate,2}{label=\arabic*)}
```

4. You should use `geometry` instead of juggling with `\osddsidemargin`,`\evensidemargin` `\hoffset` `\voffset`, &c. You can set in your preamble:

   ```
   \geometry{width=16.5cm, hmarginratio=1:1, topmargin=2.54cm, headheight=1cm}
   ```

Comment: Thanks Bernard.  I compile with LaTeX, then dvi->pdf.  I use WinEdt and MikTeX

Comment: And do you have MiKTeX or TeXLive (or MacTeX)?

Comment: No, don't have TexLive and MacTeX.  Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your first comment. With MiKTeX, try running from the command line `updmap.exe` (you can do that from MiKTeX console), both as admin and as user.

Comment: Can you please advise where the MikTex console is?  Also, what will this achieve?   I am confused.

Comment: You'll find it in the Start Menu (if you're under Windows). Vector fonts need being written in a font database  (`psfonts.map` and a couple of similar files) to be used by LaTeX, and `updmap.exe` refreshes this database.